# Deep copying and genetic algorithm

Tags: java

I am working on a project at the moment to try create a simple genetic algorithm. Regarding structure, I have a Gene that is char [] with four numbers and a chromosome which is an array of 10 gene objects.

I am trying to write a simple crossover method that creates a child from half of each of the parent chromosomes. I started with the approach below but soon realised I was just shallow copying. I have spent the last few days reading numerous posts on using the cloneable interface to implement deep copying but I have been unsuccessful with all attempts. Please could someone help me with this issue. Any tips and pointers would be grately appreciated

```
public Chromosome createChild (Chromosome parentA, Chromosome parentB)
{
    Chromosome child=new Chromosome();
    for (int i=0;i<10; i++)
    {   
        if (i<5)
        {
            child.genes[i] = parentA.genes[i]; 
        }
        else
        {
            child.genes[i] = parentB.genes[i];
        }

    }   
    return child;       
}
```

Comment: Are the `genes` mutable? That is does an operation exist that can modify their value without reassigning them?

Comment: Hey Boris, I have a mutator class which will affect the child chromosome. So this is why I need separate arrays for parent and child.

Comment: Yes and they are separate arrays already. It is just that they share the same `.gene` objects. I am still not convinced this causes any problem, though. Because I can't think of an operation that will change the value of the `gene`. Can you please share the type of these objects and if it is declared by you include their code in the question?

Comment: How exactly do you handle mutation? Give code on that.

Comment: Are you looking for `Arrays.copyOf()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us first consider the `Gene` class: according to your specifications (*I have a Gene that is char [] with four numbers*), you need a `char` array as an attribute of the class. Moreover, this class should be cloneable, then you must make this class implements the [`Cloneable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html) interface: to this end, you have to declare that the `Gene` class implements the `Cloneable` interface (simply writing `implements Cloneable` in the class definition) and you must implement the [`clone`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29) method in this class (in this method you must make a deep copy of object fields and return the cloned object, see the code below for detail).

```
import java.util.Arrays;

/*
 * Definition of the class that also includes the declaration
 * of the implementation of the Cloneable interface.
 */
public class Gene implements Cloneable {

    /*
     * The length of a gene.
     * It is defined as constant (final) in order to use the same value
     * in the whole class, where and when necessary.
     */
    private static final int GENE_LENGTH = 4;

    /*
     * In biology a gene it corresponds to a sequence of nucleic acids,
     * so I thought of naming m_sequence this field.
     */
    private char m_sequence[];

    /*
     * This constructor allows you to instantiate a new object from a char array.
     */
    public Gene(char sequence[]) {
        // The field m_sequence is initialized with a copy
        // of the array specified in the constructor.
        m_sequence = Arrays.copyOf(sequence, GENE_LENGTH);
    }

    /*
     * Simple getter method.
     * Since m_sequence is private, you need a method like this
     * in order to access elements of the array.
     */
    public char getUnit(int index) {
        return m_sequence[index];
    }

    /*
     * Simple setter method.
     * Since m_sequence is private, you need a method like this
     * in order to set the elements of the array.
     */
    public void setUnit(int index, char unit) {
        m_sequence[index] = unit;
    }

    /*
     * The Cloneable declaration requires that this class has clone method.
     * This method should return an Gene object within an Object.
     */
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        // First, we invoke the clone method of the superclass
        Gene clone = (Gene)(super.clone());

        // Then, make the deep copy of the object.
        // In this case the only field present in the Gene object is an array,
        // then you must make a deep copy of this array: in order to make a deep
        // copy of the array, you should use the Arrays.copyOf method.
        clone.m_sequence = Arrays.copyOf(m_sequence, GENE_LENGTH);

        return clone;
    }

    /*
     * Get a representation of this object as a String.
     * Just a method for simple testing.
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.toString(m_sequence);
    }
}
```

Note that to copy the array I used the method [`copyOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28char%5B%5D,%20int%29) of `Arrays` class (please read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) for more details about array copying).

A simple test to check the functioning of deep copy in `Gene` object:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    Gene g1 = new Gene(new char[]{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'});
    Gene g2 = (Gene)(g1.clone());

    // now Let's modify g1
    g1.setUnit(0, 'e');
    g1.setUnit(1, 'f');
    g1.setUnit(2, 'g');
    g1.setUnit(3, 'h');

    System.out.println("g1: " + g1);
    System.out.println("g2: " + g2);   // g2 has not changed
}
```

So, in you should change your `createChild` method as follows.

```
public class Chromosome {
    private static final int CHROMOSOME_LENGTH = 10;

    /* Array of Gene object. */
    private Gene genes[];

    /* Default constructor. */
    public Chromosome() {
        // Simply allocates an array of 10 elements.
        genes = new Gene[CHROMOSOME_LENGTH];
    }

/*
     * Simple getter method.
     * Since m_Genes is private, you need a method like this
     * in order to access elements of the array.
     */
    public Gene getGene(int index) {
        return genes[index];
    }

/*
     * Simple setter method.
     * Since m_Genes is private, you need a method like this
     * in order to set the elements of the array.
     */
    public void setGene(int index, Gene gene) {
        genes[index] = gene;
    }

    /* The method which make the cross-over. */
    public Chromosome createChild(Chromosome parentA, Chromosome parentB) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        Chromosome child = new Chromosome();

        // make the cross-over
        for (int i=0;i<10; i++)
        {   
            if (i<5)
            {
                // you need to call the clone() method
                child.genes[i] = (Gene)(parentA.genes[i].clone());
            }
            else
            {
                // you need to call the clone() method
                child.genes[i] = (Gene)(parentB.genes[i].clone());
            }
        }

        return child;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello enzom83, thank you very much for your response. I am trying to work through your solution. With the code  child.setGene(i, parentA.getGene(i)) - does the setGene method refer to the setUnit method in the Gene class? How should these setGene and getGene methods look? Apologies, I am very new to programming (6 months)..thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to enclose all the Chromosome class: I have now added it. Soon I add some detail to my answer

Comment: Thanks again my friend..I think I have got it working now because of your post

Comment: Hey enzom, I see you have edited alot of code. Are the set and get methods necessary in the Chromosome class? And how about the constructor in the Gene class? thanks

Comment: @bosra: Generally a class makes these methods available to allow any external classes to access its private members. Because the genes and chromosomes are used to encode something (which depends on the application area), it is reasonable to think that they can be read. However, based on where you use classes, you may need access to information contained in genes and/or chromosomes.

Comment: @bosra: For example, the constructor of the `Chromosome` class does not initialize the array of genes, so you must have at least the `setGene` method in order to set the genes. Instead, the costructor of the `Gene` class takes an array as an argument in order to initialize the array of char.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code for the crossover for my investigation project.
Maybe it can help you.

```
 package geneticSource;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Crossover { 
//                                          //Var for seeds
private Random rdn;            
private Random rdn2;
private Random rdn3;
private double PROB_CROSS=1;

public Crossover(double value,int seed){
    this.PROB_CROSS=value;  
    this.rdn= new Random(seed);
    this.rdn2= new Random(seed+1);
    this.rdn3= new Random(seed+2);
}



public Population Cross(Population p){
    int pointCross=0;        //Crossover point
    int n1=0;                
    int n2=0;
    double probCross=0;
    double probMut=0;
    Chromosome cr1=null;
    Chromosome cr2=null;
    List<Gen> mum1=new LinkedList<Gen>();
    List<Gen> dad1=new LinkedList<Gen>();
    List<Gen> mum2=new LinkedList<Gen>();
    List<Gen> dad2=new LinkedList<Gen>();
    ArrayList<Gen> geno1=new ArrayList<Gen>();
    ArrayList<Gen> geno2=new ArrayList<Gen>();
    Population pnew = new Population();
    //Integer[] cruce=new Integer [p.population.size()];
    ArrayList <Integer>cruceControl=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i=0;i<p.population.size();i++){
        cruceControl.add(i);
    }
    int aux=0;
    for(int i=0;i<p.population.size()/2;i++){

        n1=rdn.nextInt(cruceControl.size());
        aux=cruceControl.get(n1);
        cruceControl.remove(n1);    
        n1=aux;
        n2=rdn.nextInt(cruceControl.size());
        aux=cruceControl.get(n2);
        cruceControl.remove(n2);
        n2=aux;

        mum1=new LinkedList<Gen>();
        dad1=new LinkedList<Gen>();
        mum2=new LinkedList<Gen>();
        dad2=new LinkedList<Gen>();
        geno1=new ArrayList<Gen>();
        geno2=new ArrayList<Gen>();
        cr1=p.population.get(n1);
        cr2=p.population.get(n2);   

        probCross=this.rdn3.nextDouble();   
        probMut =this.rdn2.nextDouble();    
        if(probCross<=PROB_CROSS){               
            pointCross=rdn.nextInt(p.population.get(0).getChromosome().size());
            mum1=cr1.getChromosome().subList(0,pointCross );
            dad1=cr1.getChromosome().subList(pointCross,cr1.getChromosome().size() );
            mum2=cr2.getChromosome().subList(0,pointCross );
            dad2=cr2.getChromosome().subList(pointCross,cr2.getChromosome().size() );
            //cross;
            geno1.addAll(mum1);
            geno1.addAll(geno1.size(), dad2);
            geno2.addAll(mum2);
            geno2.addAll(geno2.size(), dad1);

            //Update the number for chromosome
            int Nva1=0;
            int Nva2=0;
            for(int j=0;j<geno1.size();j++){
                if(geno1.get(j).getValue()==1)Nva1++;
                if(geno2.get(j).getValue()==1)Nva2++;
            }
            p.population.set(n1, new Chromosome(geno1));
            p.population.get(n1).setNVariables(Nva1);
            p.population.set(n2, new Chromosome(geno2));
            p.population.get(n2).setNVariables(Nva2);
            if(Nva1<p.fminV) p.fminV=Nva1;
            if(Nva2<p.fminV) p.fminV=Nva2;
            if(Nva1>p.fmaxV) p.fmaxV=Nva1;
            if(Nva2>p.fmaxV) p.fmaxV=Nva2;

        }


    }
    int k=0;
    for(Chromosome c : p.getPopulation()){
        k=0;
        for(Gen g : c.getChromosome())
            if(g.getValue()==1)k++;
                    if(k!=c.getNVariables())System.out.println(".................................................................");
    }


    return p;
    }



  }
```

I used seed, and a count for the number of chromosomes because I used this variable for the fitness attributes.